# Is this really some coding convention to align '=' every where?

Tags: coding-style, standards

In our company we are trying to follow coding conventions and some of my Seniors are telling me few coding conventions, most of them are something I know and they are good but one of them is alignment of equality, alignment equality in the whole code looks a bit strange. I know that where we do a set of assignment specially in configuration values, we normally do equality alignment. like:

```
$params = array(
                        'dbdriver'  => $dns['scheme'],
                        'hostname'  => (isset($dns['host'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['host']) : '',
                        'username'  => (isset($dns['user'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['user']) : '',
                        'password'  => (isset($dns['pass'])) ? rawurldecode($dns['pass']) : '',
                        'database'  => (isset($dns['path'])) ? rawurldecode(substr($dns['path'], 1)) : ''
                    );
```

or like:

```
var $next_link          = '&gt;';
var $prev_link          = '&lt;';
var $last_link          = 'Last &rsaquo;';
var $uri_segment        = 3;
var $full_tag_open      = '';
var $full_tag_close     = '';
var $first_tag_open     = '';
var $first_tag_close    = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_close     = '';
var $first_url          = ''; // Alternative URL for the First Page.
var $cur_tag_open       = '&nbsp;<strong>';
var $cur_tag_close      = '</strong>';
var $next_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $next_tag_close     = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_close     = '';
var $num_tag_open       = '&nbsp;';
var $num_tag_close      = '';
var $page_query_string  = FALSE;
var $query_string_segment = 'per_page';
var $display_pages      = TRUE;
var $anchor_class       = '';
```

But when in normal code we are loading libraries, instantiating values, calling menthods and getting response in variables then still there should be equality alignment?
like there is constructor of ec2class:

```
public function __construct(array $options = array())
{
    $this->api_version = '2012-07-20';
    $this->hostname = self::DEFAULT_URL;
    $this->auth_class = 'AuthV2Query';

    return parent::__construct($options);
}
```

or place like this:

```
        $this->CI->load->library('awslib');

    $s3          = new AmazonS3();
    $bucket_name = ($is_private) ? 'private_s3_bucket' : 'public_s3_bucket';
    $bucket      = $this->CI->config->item($bucket_name);
    $options     = array(
        'fileUpload' => $file_path,
        'acl'        => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
    );

    try {
        $response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, $options);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<pre>";
        exit($e);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

so in last 2 examples, do equality alignment really matters and is there any such standard? Because I think when it is mix of instantiating libraries, loading other things, conditionally assigning values then may be equality alignment shouldn't matter as I don't see it to be more readable for me, please tell if there is some standard then please give some reference,in many frameworks and libraries e.t.c. whenever there is mix and assignment in those statements, I never saw equality alignment as such places. So please tell.

Comment: I don't realy understand what you want. Writing it this way still makes valid code and if it's a coding convention your company wants you to follow it doesn't matter if that's a convention used in many frameworks and libraries. I don't find it more readable myself but I know someone who writes his code with equality alignment because he finds it more readable but we don't have a convention in our company enforcing either way.

Comment: I actually just want to know that this alignment  of = signs do make any difference in readability, it do when it is used in providing a set of assignment in config. files but is it useful to have alignment in normal coding where mix of operations are also being used like assignment after instantiating objects e.t.c. and conditions e.t.c. ?

Comment: I think thats depends on the person as I said I know people who do this because they say it's more readable for them but I don't see it for me. So I write mine like in the first example but I work with people who write like in the second. You can enforce either way by coding standards but I don't think there is a clear answer on what is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's important to align code in a meaningful way, so you can recognize patterns.
However, it seems like you're spending a lot of time rearranging your code, which a minimum of readability gain.

In this case, if it were my company, I would try to change the convention, or at least make it a little more flexible. Especially because it's a local one. I couldn't find any documentation mentioning alignment of the equality operator as a best practice.